# Displaying Active Record default values in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb

How do I get the default value of an active record column to render in my view?

I have created a default value for a `content:string` column in a `first_lists` table:

```
create_table "first_items", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string     "content",    default: "Add a task"
t.integer  "list_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
end
```

Then in first_items_controller.rb:

```
class FirstItemsController < ApplicationController

def update
  @item = FirstItem.find(params[:id])
  if @item.update(item_params)
    render    
  else
    @list = @item.list
    render 'list/show'
  end
end

private
  def item_params
    params.require(:first_item).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Then I'm trying to render the view as a partial from the lists/show page:

```
<section class="todoapp">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 id="list-h1"><%= @list.title %></h1>
    <!-- <h1 id="list-h1"><%#= @list.name %></h1> -->
  </header>
  <section class="main">
    <ul class="todo-list">
      <%= render @list.first_items %>
      <%= render @list.second_items %>
      <%= render @list.third_items %>
      <%= render @list.fourth_items %>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" id="save-button">Save</button>
  </section>
</section>
```

_first_items.html.erb

```
<li class="item" data-id-first="<%= first_item.id %>">
    <div class="panel panel-danger box-shadow--8dp">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="panel-header-title">Mission Critical Task One</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= form_for(first_item, :remote => true) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :content, :class => "edit form-control", :id => "first-form" %>
          <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer"><input class="toggle panel-title" id="form-input" type="checkbox" unchecked=""> Complete</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I go to `lists/:id' page there is nothing rendered on the page. I was hoping that my default values would have been populated in the form.

With this setup I can get the desired output if I go into the console and manually create `:content`. Is there any way to instantiate these partials with the default column string?

EDIT
Here's the lists_controller.rb

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists = List.all
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
      if @list.save
        if request.xhr?
          render :layout => false
        else
          redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @lists = List.all
      render :index
    end
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use the `value` param like this on the text_field object:

```
<%= f.text_field :content, :class => "edit form-control", :id => "first-form", value: first_item.content %>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to have worked. I even tried `value: "Add a task"`. Note that there's a typo in your answer; 'context' should be 'content' ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to answer the first line of your question.

```
MyKlass.columns_hash["column_name"].default
```

or, in your example,

```
FirstList.columns_hash["content"].default
```